# Network Hardware supports SMTP, but no AUTH information... Need to Send emails through SMTP with AUTH

Tags: email, email-server, smtp, smtp-auth

I have a network device that supports sending email notifications, but doesn't provide for the username and password. I would like to point this device to an internal system which would then take care of sending the email using our actual email server. (Which requires a username and password.) Do you know of any service program that I could run on Windows which would take care of this for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Point it at one of your MX servers. If those don't accept unauthenticated mail something is very wrong (or you intentionally don't receive mail from the internet). Then you just have to worry about getting the message past your spam filters.

You could also alter your MTA to accept without auth from that devices IP address.

Comment: I use hosted email servers, so this is a no go. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [hMailServer](http://www.hmailserver.com/) to only accept mails from that device and then relay it to a "real" mail server with SMTP-AUTH.

Answer (score 0):

IIS will do this for you,

this is an example how to do it with for Google Mail.

http://routerjanitor.blogspot.com/2011/08/google-apps-iis-smtp-relay.html

Of course the TCP port and the smart host will need to be altered for your solution.